# Constituent badge not awarded even after voting for candidates in the recent moderator elections

Tags: support, badges, election

I voted for multiple candidates in the recently concluded moderator elections. Today, I checked the badges section and came across the `Constituent` badge and realised I should have had one.

Why was it not awarded to me? Is it a bug or there is some hidden rule that makes me ineligible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a <strike>wild</strike> educated guess, but I suppose you voted in the [primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=primary), not in the actual [election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=election).

The [badge description](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=silver) isn't very specific on this:

[image: Voted for a candidate in an election]

But I can tell you from my personal experience that voting in the primary does **not** award the badge.

Comment: What is the difference primary and actual elections?

Comment: In the [primary](http://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=primary), you can cast up or downvotes on each candidate's nomination. The 10 candidates with the best scores move on to the actual [election](http://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=election), where you can pick your three favorites.

Comment: To add more: In the primary election, you can cast your vote to all the candidates. And in actual election, you vote for 3 persons as first choice, second choice and third choice

Comment: Yes, I had participated in the primary election. The badge description should be changed to something like `"Voted for a candidate in an election's finals"` to make it clear.

Comment: @userSeven7s: I agree. You could open a new question with a feature request. I already edited the entry in [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)