# Clarify the Constituent badge description

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badge-description

From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136927/constituent-badge-not-awarded-even-after-voting-for-candidates-in-the-recent-mod) post its very clear that the `Constituent` badge's description is not precise.

The current description reads

> Voted for a candidate in an [election](https://stackoverflow.com/election)

which doesn't specify whether it is sufficient or not to vote in the primary phase.

Please update the description to a more accurate one.

Comment: Why are making same feature request again?

Comment: coz I was asked to. It was a question initially and wasnt known if it was a bug or misunderstanding on my side. I removed the feature-request tag from previous question.

Comment: Before asking question, you should have edited question. You have removed tag after posting question. that's why I commented wrongly. Sry :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the next build the badge description will read:

> Voted for a candidate in the final phase of an election.